# Java GUI "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, compilation, symbols

Can somebody explain to me why it can not find 'symbol' I have done a little looking up but it does not make sense to me. I am using IDE. ( there is a red line under: jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);) same thing with the second block, the third is the compiling information in IDE.  Can someone explain this, BTW IDE did this so im not sure what to do.
problem area 1:

```
 jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
}

 jTextField3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }



Updating property file: C:\Users\nate\Documents\Jeopardy\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\nate\Documents\Jeopardy\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\nate\Documents\Jeopardy\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\nate\Documents\Jeopardy\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\nate\Documents\Jeopardy\build\classes
C:\Users\nate\Documents\Jeopardy\src\jeopardy\NewJFrame.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
  symbol: method jTextField1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent)
C:\Users\nate\Documents\Jeopardy\src\jeopardy\NewJFrame.java:212: error: cannot find symbol
                jTextField3ActionPerformed(evt);
  symbol: method jTextField3ActionPerformed(ActionEvent)
2 errors
C:\Users\nate\Documents\Jeopardy\nbproject\build-impl.xml:926: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\nate\Documents\Jeopardy\nbproject\build-impl.xml:268: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: I would suggest that the methods `jTextField1ActionPerformed` and `jTextField3ActionPerformed` no longer exist or the method signatures no longer match

Comment: You need to show us the methods that you think match the ones that have been flagged by the compiler. Regarding, `"BTW IDE did this so im not sure what to do."` -- time to not use the IDe to generate code for you, at least you should avoid using code generation until you understand a little Java first.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels thanks

Comment: @MadProgrammer I put the methods in and it  works now thanks!